# How can I sniff packets from an unsecured wireless network?

Tags: security, wireless-networking, sniffing, wep

I am interested in being able log packets going over a unsecured wireless network. Specifically, I want to see HTTP POST / GET requests and responses going between the router and computers on the network. Which software do people use for this? I am running OSX and I have a RT73 chipset USB wireless card that supports passive mode.

Is there a way to do this over WEP encrypted networks (provided I know the key) as well?

Comment: Hrrrmmmf... I suppose my comments that *were* here (and not deleted by me) belonged on meta anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommended [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) which will track any traffic on a particular network card.

From a Wireless router perspective I am not aware of any software that can do this unless the router itself is linux based in which case you can use [tcpdump](http://www.tcpdump.org/)

Comment: If you know the WEP or WPA password for the wireless network, you can see (and sniff) all the traffic on it. WEP/WPA only prevent users who don't know the password from seeing the traffic; once you know the password it's all open to you.

Comment: thank you, i have used wireshark in the past, but i had no idea it was this powerful. worked perfect : )

Comment: @BarryBrown - can you tell the steps that is done?

Answer (score 3):

A program like [AirMagnet](http://www.airmagnet.com/) will allow you to sniff directly from your wireless adapter, even if you aren't connected to the networks.

A program like [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/) will allow you to sniff any network you are connected to.